# How do I add new field in existing JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, parsing

I have JSON with 10000 unique records and I need to add another field with a unique value to every record. How do I add that?

```
[
{
_id: "5fffd08e62575323d40fca6f",
wardName: "CIC",
region: "ABC",
location: "AAA",
specialism: "CSR",
__v: 0
},
.
.
.
]
```

The JSON is stored in variable **showWard**. How do I add an **action** field in my JSON with value = './wardName' where wardName is already a field in my JSON?
This is my current code:

```
app.get('/wards', function (req, res) {
    Ward.find({}, function (err, showWard) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); return; }
        return res.send(showWard);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's an array of objects and not [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) -> [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `.map()`? I don't know the logic for determinate the gender, but in `Ward.find()` callback you can add a thing like that:

```
app.get('/wards', function (req, res) {
    Ward.find({}, function (err, showWard) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); return; }

        const newShowWard = showWard.map(ward => {
            ward.gender = "BOH"; 
            return ward;
        })
        
        return res.send(newShowWard);
    });
});
```

Comment: If you're not going to use the return value of `.map()` then you shouldn't use `.map()`

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean? If he assign the new object at a variable and use `res.send(variable)`, that's not goog?

Comment: Your example modifies `showWard` in-place, and you're not using the array returned by `.map()`. This should be a `.forEach()` call (without the `return ward;` at the end)

Comment: Ah ok, right. Unfortunately I imply many things.